# How to use a MATLAB file as a file source in GNU Radio

Tags: matlab, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I designed a filter and applied it to a random noise signal using SPTool in MATLAB. My noise signal was `x = (1/sqrt(2))*(randn(1024,1)+j*randn(1024,1))`

Once I've applied my filter to this noise signal, how can I take that filtered signal and use it as a file source in GNU Radio Companion (which I will connect to QT GUI Frequency Sink)? I tried exporting the signal using SPTool but I'm unsure what file extension I can use for GNU Radio. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fwrite` with the right *precision* parameter that gives you float 32 binaries.

Or just use the octave/Matlab [scripts in GNU Radio](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/master/gr-utils/octave/write_complex_binary.m) that do exactly that: write raw binary data. For more info, see the GNU Radio FAQ entry on the file format. (On https://wiki.gnuradio.org )

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction. But what do I put for the 'A' argument `fwrite(fileID,A,precision)`? I have all my specifications in SPTool, and I can export the filtered noise to my workspace but fwrite doesn't support struct classes. How do I get the information I created in SPTool to something readable by fwrite? Thanks.

Comment: just use some form of iterable/vector.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I know the 'A' argument needs to be some form of vector, but what I don't know is how to take my filtered noise that I made with SPTool and put it in a format that fwrite can use (i.e. a vector). When I export the filtered noise, it is exported in my workspace as a struct, not a vector. I can't just put any random vector as 'A', then I wouldn't be writing anything useful to my file for GNU Radio.

Comment: to extract from your struct, whatever it contains, a vector of samples. Docs of SPtool should say what the fields in that struct are, and which one is the sample vector.

Comment: Okay so I went into my struct and took the data part out of it. filteredNoise was my struct and data was what I wanted. fwrite(fileID,filteredNoise.data,float32) seemed to work for me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a .mat file, another option is to use a Vector Source block putting in the Vector field:

`loadmat('filename')['varname'].flatten()`

For this to work you need to:

```
import numpy
from scipy.io import loadmat
```

Note this loads the whole file in memory (but you can specify which variables to load from the file if that's a problem). Also if the data is stored as float64 (as is the norm in Matlab) then I think there could be some rounding/truncation since GR Vector Source expects float32 (don't know enough about how SWIG handles that).